# How to count variables in Angular Js stub with value not NULL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

this is my seperate stub file..

```
'requests': [
    {
        firstName: 'Richard',
        lastName: 'Love',
        purchase: '999999999',
        grant: 'Privlidge'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Richard',
        lastName: 'Love',
        purchase: '999999999',
        grant: 'Block'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Richard',
        lastName: 'Love',
        purchase: '999999999',
        grant: null

    }
```

I need to count number of requests with 'grant' value Not Null (! null), here it should return 2

this is the service which i am using to fetch record

```
  getRequestData: {
         method: 'GET',
         url: config.refrenceUrl + 'request-screen',
         isArray: false
     },
```

Please let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to loop over the array of request and count how many `req['grant'] !== null` are in the array (See snippet below and play around with the array of `request` in order to see how changes the *grants not null*)

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.wizard = {
      'requests': [{
          firstName: 'Richard',
          lastName: 'Love',
          purchase: '999999999',
          grant: 'Privlidge'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Richard',
          lastName: 'Love',
          purchase: '999999999',
          grant: 'Block'
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Richard',
          lastName: 'Love',
          purchase: '999999999',
          grant: null
        }
      ],
      grantNotNullCount: fnGrantNotNullCount
    };

    return vm.wizard;

    function fnGrantNotNullCount() {
      var c = 0;

      angular.forEach(vm.wizard.requests, function(req) {
        if (req['grant'] !== null) {
          c++;
        }
      });

      return c;
    }


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as c">

  Requests
  <div ng-repeat="req in c.requests">
    <span>{{req}}</span><br/>
  </div>
 <br/>
  <strong>grants not null:</strong>
  <span ng-bind="c.grantNotNullCount()"></span>
  
</div>
```